# Tags for Emacs: Relationship between etags, ebrowse, cscope, GNU Global and exuberant ctags

Tags: emacs, cscope, cedet, gnu-global

I work on C++ projects, and I went through Alex Ott's [guide to CEDET](http://alexott.net/en/writings/emacs-devenv/EmacsCedet.html) and other threads about tags in StackOverflow, but I am still confused about how Emacs interfaces with these different tag systems to facilitate autocompletion, the looking up of definitions, navigation of source code base or the previewing of doc-strings.

1. What is the difference (e.g. in terms of features) between  `etags`, `ebrowse`, [`exuberant ctags`](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/), [`cscope`](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/), [`GNU Global`](http://www.gnu.org/software/global/) and [`GTags`](http://code.google.com/p/google-gtags/wiki/GTagsEmacsClient)? What do I need to do to use them in **Emacs**?
2. Do I need semantic/senator (CEDET) if I want to use tags to navigate/autocomplete symbols?
3. What does semantic bring to the table on top of these different tag utilities? How does it interface with these tools?

Comment: Judging by [the trunk](http://code.google.com/p/google-gtags/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk), the `GTags` project you linked to is quite dead. If someone's talking about`gtags`, they're probably referring to GNU Global.

Comment: Add [Universal Ctags](https://github.com/universal-ctags/ctags) -- the maintained fork of Exuberant Ctags -- to the mix :) [ggtags](https://github.com/leoliu/ggtags) is the Emacs package for this.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

That's as a good question as I've recently read here, so I'll try explain the difference in more detail:

**Point 1:**

`etags` and `ctags` both generate an index (a.k.a. tag/TAGS) file of language objects found in source files that allows these items to be quickly and easily located by a text editor or other utility. A tag signifies a language object for which an index entry is available (or, alternatively, the index entry created for that object). The tags generated by ctags are richer in terms of metadata, but Emacs cannot interpret the additional data anyways, so you should consider them more or less the same (the main advantage of `ctags` would be its support for more languages). The primary use for the tags files is looking up class/method/function/constant/etc declaration/definitions.

`cscope` is much more powerful beast (at least as far as C/C++ and Java are concerned). While it operates on more or less the same principle (generating a file of useful metadata) it allows you do some fancier things like find all references to a symbol, see where a function is being invoked, etc (you can find definitions as well).

To sum it up:

`ctags` one allows you to navigate to symbol declaration/definitions (what some would call a *one-way lookup*). `ctags` is a general purpose tool useful for many languages.

On the other hand (as mentioned on the project's page) `cscope` allows you to:

- Go to the declaration of a symbol
- Show a selectable list of all references to a symbol
- Search for any global definition
- Functions called by a function
- Functions calling a function
- Search for a text string
- Search for a regular expression pattern
- Find a file
- Find all files including a file

It should come as no surprise to anyone at this point, that when I deal with C/C++ projects I make heavy use of `cscope` and care very little about `ctags`. When dealing with other languages the situation would obviously be reversed.

**Point 2.**

To have intelligent autocompletion you need a true [source code parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) (like semantic), otherwise you won't know the types of the objects (for instance) in your applications and the methods that can be invoked on them. You can have an autocompletion based on many different sources, but to get the best results you'll ultimately need a parser. Same goes for syntax highlighting - currently syntax highlighting in Emacs major modes is based simply on regular expressions and that's very fragile and error prone. Hopefully with the inclusion of semantic in Emacs 23.2 (it used to be an external package before that) we'll start seeing more uses for it (like using it to analyse a buffer source code to properly highlight it)

Since Emacs 24.1 semantic is usable from the Emacs completion framework. The easiest way to test it is to open up a C source code file and typing <kbd>M-TAB</kbd> or <kbd>C-M-i</kbd> and watch as semantic automagically completes for you. For languages where semantic is not enabled by default, you can add it the following line to your major mode hook of choice:

```
(add-to-list 'completion-at-point-functions 'semantic-completion-at-point-function)
```

**Point 3.**

semantic brings true code awareness (for the few languages it currently supports) and closes the gap between IDEs and Emacs. It doesn't really interface with tools like `etags` and `cscope`, but it doesn't mean you cannot use them together.

Hopefully my explanations make sense and will be useful to you.

P.S. I'm not quite familiar with `global` and `ebrowse`, but if memory serves me they made use of etags.

Comment: This is great. Thanks! Do you know how can I use `cscope` in Emacs? I read about `xcscope.el` on the EmacsWiki [here](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/CScopeAndEmacs) but I could not find a link to the file. Also, which `.el` file do you use to get `cscope` with Emacs?

Comment: `xcscope.el` is located in `cscope/contrib/xcscope/` (this being in the distribution package). That's what I use.

Comment: One more question: How does `semantic` compare with `cscope`? In terms of navigating through the source code, does semantic provide any functionality that `cscope` doesn't? Do you use both?

Comment: I don't believe GNU Global use etags, btw. IIRC it maintains and queries a 'proper' database (rather than scanning a flat text file), which has numerous performance benefits both for querying and (especially) for updating the tags.

Comment: @BozhidarBatsov When you said `For languages where semantic is not enabled by default, you can add the following line to your major mode hook of choice ... <code>`. What does that code snippet exactly do?

Comment: GNU Global is arguably more powerful than `cscope`, as it can do everything `cscope` can do, but has more [integrations](https://github.com/oracle/opengrok/wiki/Comparison-with-Similar-Tools).  Answer should be updated to reflect this.

Answer (score 47):

I'll try to add some explanations to 1.

**What is it?**

- Etags is a command to generate 'TAGS' file which is the tag file for Emacs. You can use the file with etags.el which is part of emacs package.
- Ctags is a command to generate 'tags' file which is the tag file for vi.  Universal Ctags, the successor of Exuberant Ctags, can generate 'TAGS' file by the -e option, supporting more than 41 programming languages.
- Cscope is an all-in-one source code browsing tool for C language. It has own fine CUI (character user interface) and tag databases (cscope.in.out, cscope.out, cscope.po.out). You can use cscope from Emacs using xcscope.el which is part of cscope package.
- GNU GLOBAL is a source code tagging system. Though it is similar to above tools, it differs from them at the point of that it is dependent from any editor, and it has no user interface except for command line. Gtags is a command to generate tag files for GLOBAL (GTAGS, GRTAGS, GPATH). You can use GLOBAL from emacs using gtags.el which is part of GLOBAL package. In addition to this, there are many elisp libraries for it (xgtags.el, ggtags.el, anything-gtags.el, helm-gtags.el, etc).

**Comparison**

- Ctags and etags treat only definitions. Cscope and GNU GLOBAL treat not only definitions but also references.
- Ctags and etags use a flat text tag file. Cscope and GNU GLOBAL use key-value tag databases.
- Cscope and GNU GLOBAL have a grep like search engine and incremental updating facility of tag files.

**Combination**

You can combine Universal Ctags's rich language support and GNU GLOBAL's database facility by using ctags as a plug-in parser of GLOBAL.

Try the following: (requires GLOBAL-6.5.3+ and Universal Ctags respectively)

Building GNU GLOBAL:

```
$ ./configure --with-universal-ctags=/usr/local/bin/ctags
$ sudo make install
```

Usage:

```
$ export GTAGSCONF=/usr/local/share/gtags/gtags.conf
$ export GTAGSLABEL=new-ctags
$ gtags                     # invokes Universal Ctags internally
$ emacs -f gtags-mode       # load gtags.el
```

(However, you cannot treat references by this method, because ctags don't treat references.)

You can also use cscope as a client of GNU GLOBAL. GLOBAL package includes a command named 'gtags-cscope' which is a port of cscope, that is, it is cscope itself except that it use GLOBAL as a search engine instead of cscope's one.

```
$ gtags-cscope          # this is GLOBAL version of cscope
```

With the combinations, you can use cscope for 41 languages.

Good luck!

Comment: For users on Debian and derivatives like Ubuntu: The GNU GLOBAL webpage warns that the .deb packages that ship with these Linux distributions is dated, and should not be used. In my case GLOBAL was on version 5.7.1, and I couldn't get gtags.el, ggtags.el or helm-gtags.el to work properly on Emacs 24. Compiling GNU GLOBAL 6.5 from scratch, with support for Exuberant Ctags (I used 5.8) worked a treat. (Thanks for the excellent pointers, @shigio).

Answer (score 10):

### TAGS files contain definitions

A `TAGS` file contains a list of where functions and classes are defined. It is usually placed in the root of a project and looks like this:

```
^L
configure,3945
as_fn_success () { as_fn_return 0; }^?as_fn_success^A180,5465
as_fn_failure () { as_fn_return 1; }^?as_fn_failure^A181,5502
as_fn_ret_success () { return 0; }^?as_fn_ret_success^A182,5539
as_fn_ret_failure () { return 1; }^?as_fn_ret_failure^A183,5574
```

This enables Emacs to find definitions. Basic navigation is built-in with `find-tag`, but [`etags-select`](http://melpa.org/#/etags-select) provides a nicer UI when there are multiple matches.

You can also uses TAGS files for code completion. For example, [company's etags backend uses TAGS files](https://github.com/company-mode/company-mode/blob/master/company-etags.el).

### TAGS files can be built by different tools

[`ctags`](https://ctags.io/) (formerly known as 'universal ctags' or 'exuberant ctags') can generate TAGS files and supports the widest range of languages. It is actively maintained on github.

Emacs ships with two programs that generate TAGS files, called `etags` and `ctags`. Emacs' `ctags` is just `etags` with the same CLI interface as universal ctags. To avoid confusion, many distros rename these programs (e.g. `ctags.emacs24` on Debian).

There are also language specific tools for generating TAGS files, such as [`jsctags`](https://github.com/ramitos/jsctags) and [`hasktags`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hasktags).

### Other file formats

`ebrowse` is a C program shipped with Emacs. It indexes C/C++ code and generates a `BROWSE` file. ebrowse.el provides the usual find definition and completion. You can also open the `BROWSE` file directly in Emacs to get an overview of the classes/function defined a codebase.

[GNU Global](http://www.gnu.org/software/global/) has its own database format, which consists of a `GTAGS`, `GRTAGS` and `GPATH` file. You can generate these files with the `gtags` command, which parses C/C++ code. For other languages, GNU Global can read files generated by universal ctags.

GNU Global also provides a CLI interface for asking more sophisticated questions, like 'where is this symbol mentioned?'. It ships with an Emacs package gtags.el, but [ggtags.el](https://github.com/leoliu/ggtags) is also popular for accessing GNU Global databases.

[Cscope](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/) is similar in spirit to GNU Global: it parses C/C++ into its own database format. It can also answer questions like 'find all callers/callees of this funciton'.

See also [this HN discussion comparing global and cscope](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=8617027).

### Client/Server projects

[rtags](https://github.com/Andersbakken/rtags) parses and indexes C/C++ using a persistent server. It uses the clang parser, so it handles C++ really well. It ships with an Emacs package to query the server.

[google-gtags](https://code.google.com/archive/p/google-gtags/) was a project where a large TAGS file would be stored on a server. When you queried the server, it would provide a subset of the TAGS file that was relevant to your search.

### Semantic (CEDET)

Semantic is a built-in Emacs package that contains a parser for C/C++, so it can find definitions too. It can also import data from TAGS files, csope databases, and other sources. CEDET also includes IDE style functionality that uses this data, e.g. generating UML diagrams of class hierarchies.

Answer (score 8):

*[answer updated from [shigio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15169556/915044)'s]*

I'll try to add some explanations to part 1 of the question.

**What is it?**

1. [Etags](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Create-Tags-Table.html#Create-Tags-Table) generates a `TAGS` file which is the [tag file format for Emacs](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsTags). You can use an Etags file with `etags.el` which is part of Emacs.
2. `Ctags` is the generic term for anything that can generate a `tags` file, which is the native tag file format for Vi. [Universal Ctags](https://ctags.io/) (aka `UCtags`, formerly Exuberant Ctags) can also generate Etags with the `-e` option.
3. [Cscope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cscope) is an all-in-one source code browsing tool for C (with lesser support for C++ and Java), with its own tag databases (`cscope.in.out`, `cscope.out`, `cscope.po.out`) and [TUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text-based_user_interface). Cscope support is built-in to Vim; you can use Cscope from Emacs using the [xcscope.el package](https://github.com/dkogan/xcscope.el). There are also [Cscope-based GUIs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cscope#GUI_frontends).
4. [GNU GLOBAL](https://www.gnu.org/software/global/) (aka `Gtags`) is yet another source code tagging system (with significant differences--see next section), in that it also generates tag files.

**Comparison**

- Ctags and Etags treat only definitions (of, e.g., variables and functions). Cscope and Gtags also treat references.
- Ctags and Etags tag files are [flat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_file_database). Cscope and Gtags tagfiles are more powerful [key-value databases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key-value_database), which allows (e.g.) incremental update.
- Cscope and Gtags have a `grep`-like search engine.
- Ctags has built-in support for more languages and data formats: see the current-in-repository [list of Universal Ctags parsers](https://github.com/universal-ctags/ctags/tree/master/parsers). UCtags also has [documented how to develop your own parser](http://docs.ctags.io/en/latest/optlib.html#submitting-an-optlib-to-universal-ctags-project).
- Cscope and Gtags are editor-independent.
- Gtags does not provide its own user interface, but can currently (Oct 2016) be used from commandline (CLI), Emacs and relatives, Vi and relatives, `less` (pager), [Doxygen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doxygen), and any web browser.
- Gtags provides `gtags.el` via the GLOBAL package, but there are also many other elisp extensions, including xgtags.el, ggtags.el, anything-gtags.el, helm-gtags.el.

**Combination**

You can combine Universal Ctags' rich language support with Gtags' database facility and numerous extensions by using Ctags as a [GLOBAL plug-in parser](https://www.gnu.org/software/global/manual/global.html#Plug_002din):

```
# build GNU GLOBAL
./configure --with-exuberant-ctags=/usr/local/bin/ctags
sudo make install

# use it
export GTAGSCONF=/usr/local/share/gtags/gtags.conf
export GTAGSLABEL=ctags
gtags                     # invokes Universal Ctags internally
emacs -f gtags-mode       # load gtags.el
```

Note again that if you use Ctags as the parser for your Gtags, you lose the ability to treat references (e.g., variable usage, function calls) which Gtags would otherwise provide. Essentially, you trade off Gtags' reference tracking for Ctags' greater built-in language support.

You can also use Cscope as a client of Gtags: [`gtags-cscope`](https://www.gnu.org/software/global/manual/global.html#Gtags_002dcscope).

Good luck!

Comment: I read: "Note again that if you use Ctags as the parser for your Gtags, you lose the ability to treat references (e.g., variable usage, function calls) which Gtags would otherwise provide. Essentially, you trade off Gtags' reference tracking for Ctags' greater built-in language support."  Is that true for the old ctags shipped with Emacs, or is it still true for Universal Ctags?  Also, I read "combine Universal Ctag's rich language" but in the shell snippet it uses `--with-exuberant-ctags=...` when now as of 2019 there is a `--with-universal-ctags` option. Should that be changed to the latter?

Answer (score 3):

I haven't actually checked, but according to CEDET manual (http://www.randomsample.de/cedetdocs/common/cedet/CScope.html):

semantic can use CScope as a back end for database searches. To enable it, use:

```
 (semanticdb-enable-cscope-databases)
```

This will enable the use of cscope for all C and C++ buffers.

CScope will then be used for project-wide searches as a backup when pre-existing semantic database searches may not have parsed all your files.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in Emacs 24.3.1, using the vanilla CEDET 2.0 that ships with it (no semanticdb-enable-cscope-databases method).