# Does Universal Ctags prevent reference lookup when used as a GNU Global "backend"?

Tags: emacs, gnu-global, universal-ctags

In https://stackoverflow.com/a/39905971/257924 I read:

> Note again that if you use Ctags as the parser for your Gtags, you lose the ability to treat references (e.g., variable usage, function calls) which Gtags would otherwise provide. Essentially, you trade off Gtags' reference tracking for Ctags' greater built-in language support.

That was a old answer, so now, in 2019, using GNU Global 6.6.3 and compiled with `--with-universal-ctags`, does that trade off still exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the trade-off still exists.