# how to tell emacs to actually use the ctags file I created

Tags: emacs, vi, ctags, exuberant-ctags

Not finding what i'm looking for.

Want to enable/start using Ctags with emacs & Vim (setting this up for a team, some use vi some use emacs)

I can:  Run "ctags -e -f ./.ctags LONG_LIST_OF_FILES  (I do this in a Makefile)

note: I need to do it this way, because I need to control what is and is not scanned.
A recursive search will be a problem - as there are C files in sub directories that
do not apply to this situation

Result:  the file exists, it seems happy but .. how do I tell emacs - yea, there is a ctags file here..

Actually - its more like this:

```
   PROJECT_DOG=/home/foobar/dog
   $(CTAG_FILE) = $(PROJECT_DOG)/.ctags

   Then I have a number of subdirectories - sort of like this:

      $(PROJECT_DOG)/libtail/src
      $(PROJECT_DOG)/libtail/include

      $(PROJECT_DOG)/liblegs/src
      $(PROJECT_DOG)/liblegs/include

      $(PROJECT_DOG)/libtail/src
      $(PROJECT_DOG)/libtail/include

      $(PROJECT_DOG)/libnose/src
      $(PROJECT_DOG)/libnose/include
      .. and numerous other "lib" like directories ..
```

The single top level .ctags file covers the entire project... (all "lib directories")

Problem statement:

I "visit" a file in emacs - I'm expecting ctags to appear.. but it is not
Same problem with VI and GVIM.

It seems that both tools do not know the tags file exist...

Tried looking here:
Google finds plenty of examples of how to install ctags, and run ctags
but - nothing about how to "activate?" (if that is the correct word) the tags.

https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BuildTags
[Tags for Emacs: Relationship between etags, ebrowse, cscope, GNU Global and exuberant ctags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12922526/tags-for-emacs-relationship-between-etags-ebrowse-cscope-gnu-global-and-exub)
http://timothypratley.blogspot.com/2008/07/ctags.html

And a number of other places - no luck.

MY HOPE IS THIS:

When I visit a file in a directory - the tool (emacs/vi) automatically discovers the "tags" file in that directory, or one of the several parent directories up unto the root.  The example being:  I open the file:   $(PROJECT_DOG)/libtail/src, but the ctags file is 2 levels up.

Or something like that..

Comment: what emacs library for tags are you using?  `ggtags` w/ exuberant-ctags works quite well, but the tags files are different (it will look for a `GTAGS` file in the project directory).  My guess is whatever library you're using is expecting a tags file called `TAGS` or similar.

Comment: Yes, `TAGS` is the standard filename expected by Emacs.  But it will prompt you for the file, so you can enter something different if necessary.  What do you mean by "expecting ctags to appear"?? Tags are used on demand; if you don't try to do something with them, they're not going to be used.  Try `M-x find-tag` for instance.